# Use motion when putting

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, normal-mode

A very common use case I'm having is to copy something (let's say a word) and I want to paste it in another context (let's say a word with quotes). The way I do it is:

```
const char *foobar(void) {
    return "barfoo";
}
```

there, as my cursor is on foobar:

```
const char *foo|bar(void) {
```

I could do something like:

```
yiw
```

to copy content. Then:

```
j
```

to move within the returned string:

```
    return "bar|foo";
```

And then I should do:

```
vi"p
```

to paste `foobar` within the quotes:

```
    return "foobar|";
```

My question is whether there's a way to use a motion to `put`, the same way it is possible to `yank`, what I'd love to do is something like:

```
pi"
```

which obviously wouldn't work. I find it feels weird to have to use a visual to apply a paste within a motion, but everybody I asked told me it's not possible. If it is indeed not, what would be the rationale of having the action `put` not accepting a motion‽

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming `pi"` would work, it would then mean that you will need at least 2 chars to simply put at cursor position - you can't simply use `p` by itself! (which is, after all, the most often used paste operation). With yank, it's clear you have to copy "something", so there is an asymmetry between the two.

BTW, with Kana's [operator replace](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-replace), you can simply do something like `_i"` to replace text with previous yanked text from default register. Or `__` to replace a line
(assuming you mapped `_` as the docs suggest).

Comment: well, I agree <kbd>p</kbd> is the most used put operation, but it's behaviour is always assuming a lot in how and where to put. Putting something taken by <kbd>C-v</kdb> will behave differently than when it's taken by <kbd>yiw</kdb. and yet differently than with <kbd>yy</kbd>, which might not always be the preferred way to put. So the default <kbd>p</kbd> seems odd and not in line with general behaviour. The operator replace sounds interesting though, I'll give it a try ;-)

Comment: You asked about a rationale: yank "something" (range) != put "somewhere" (position). If `p` would accept a range (motion, text-object), you couldn't use `p` alone. I'm not saying that I like it, that I agree with it etc. - it's just why I think it is like it is.

Comment: A few other plugin options: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) and [regreplop.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2702).

Comment: I'm giving a try to kana's `operator-replace`, and it's very likely I'll like it, and I might actually consider replace `p` with it (and then `gp` with `p` to keep the old behaviour within easy reach) :->